# Sort CSV file in C

Tags: c, sorting, csv

Hello i made a program reading data from a sensor into a csv file.

```
void sensor_read(int fd)
{

    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    do{
        while(!read(fd, &c, 1));
        printf("%c\n",c);
    }while (c!='$');

    do{
        while(!read(fd, &c, 1));
        fp = fopen("/var/www/Sensor_data.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fp, "%c%", c);
        printf("%c",c);
        fclose(fp);
    }while (c!='\n');
}
```

The data read looks like this: 
meas,587.088518,**1.093652,1.988754,3522.934999,3522.013512,690.454784,896.428414,115.473813**,23.875225,14.871661,2.847579,805.726416

I only need the 7 values marked, so my question is what is a good way to retrieve these data from the file? To do it when writing the file or to do it after the file have been made and save into a new file maybe? and maybe some examples of how to do this :)

In advance Thanks!

Comment: you may look at sort.c in coreutils linux package sources... however, it is quite long and complex code...

Comment: What does the title of the question have to do with the question? The title sounds like you want to *sort* values (or rows?) in a CSV file, but the body of the question looks like you're just trying to *extract* a subset of the rows. Which is it? (For what it's worth, you don't necessarily need a custom program to do this -- something like the `cut` utility can do this easily. And `awk` is basically built for manipulating CSV files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double values[7] = {0};
fscanf(fp, "meas,%*lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &values[0],  &values[1],
     &values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]);
```

Comment: thanks cant quite get it to work, i have to add this after the fopen right? and then fprint(....) after right? when i do that i get 7 data in file but not the measured ones.

Comment: @Jacob what is the data that you get after doing this? BTW you have to `fprintf()` with `%lf` not `%c%`, also you could change the first `do...while()` with the answer and the second `do...while()` with the `fprintf()`, that should work.

Comment: I get -0.00027, -0.00027, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 when i use printf("%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", &values[0],  &values[1], &values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]); so it seems like it dont read from the file or something? ive written my new code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
void sensor_read(int fd )
{

    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    double values[7] = {0};
    fp = fopen("/var/www/Sensor_data.txt", "w");
    do {
        while(!read(fd, &c, 1));
        printf("%c\n",c);

        fscanf(fp, "meas,%*lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &values[0],  &values[1],&values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]);
    } while (c!='$');

    do {
        while(!read(fd, &c, 1));

        //fscanf(fp, "meas,%*lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &values[0],  &values[1],
        //&values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]);

        //fprintf(fp, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", &values[0],  &values[1],
        //&values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]);

        printf("%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", &values[0],  &values[1], &values[2], &values[3], &values[4], &values[5], &values[6]);


    } while (c!='\n');

    fclose(fp);
}
```

the input from sensor is:

`$meas,587.088518,1.093652,1.988754,3522.934999,3522.013512,690.454784,896.428414,115.473813,23.875225,14.871661,2.847579,805.726416`